# Linux DMA API: specifying address increment behavior?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dma

I am writing a driver for [Altera Soc Developement Kit](http://www.altera.com/products/devkits/altera/kit-cyclone-v-soc.html) and need to support two modes of data transfer to/from a FPGA:

1. **FIFO transfers**: When writing to (or reading from) an FPGA FIFO, the destination (or source) address must not be incremented by the DMA controller.
2. **non-FIFO transfers**:  These are normal (RAM-like) transfers where both the source and destination addresses require an increment for each word transferred.

The particular DMA controller I am using is the CoreLink DMA-330 DMA Controller and its Linux driver is pl330.c (drivers/dma/pl330.c).  This DMA controller does provide a mechanism to switch between "Fixed-address burst" and "Incrementing-address burst" (these are synonymous with my "FIFO transfers" and "non-FIFO transfers").  The pl330 driver specifies which behavior it wants by setting the appropriate bits in the CCRn register

```
#define CC_SRCINC       (1 << 0)
#define CC_DSTINC       (1 << 14)
```

**My question**: it is not at all clear to me how clients of the pl330 (my driver, for example) should specify the address-incrementing behavior.

The [DMA engine client API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dmaengine/client.txt) says nothing about how to specify this while the [DMA engine provider API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dmaengine/provider.txt) simply states:

> Addresses pointing to RAM are typically incremented (or decremented)
>   after each transfer. In case of a ring buffer, they may loop
>   (DMA_CYCLIC). Addresses pointing to a device's register (e.g. a FIFO)
>   are typically fixed.

without giving any detail as to how the address types are communicated to providers (in my case the pl300 driver).

The in the pl330_prep_slave_sg method it does:

```
 if (direction == DMA_MEM_TO_DEV) {                  
     desc->rqcfg.src_inc = 1;                        
     desc->rqcfg.dst_inc = 0;                        
     desc->req.rqtype = MEMTODEV;                    
     fill_px(&desc->px,                              
         addr, sg_dma_address(sg), sg_dma_len(sg));  
 } else {                                            
     desc->rqcfg.src_inc = 0;                        
     desc->rqcfg.dst_inc = 1;                        
     desc->req.rqtype = DEVTOMEM;                    
     fill_px(&desc->px,                              
         sg_dma_address(sg), addr, sg_dma_len(sg));  
 }
```

where later, the desc->rqcfg.src_inc, and desc->rqcfg.dst_inc are used by the driver to specify the address-increment behavior.

This implies the following:

- Specifying a direction = DMA_MEM_TO_DEV means the client wishes to pull data from a FIFO into RAM.  And presumably DMA_DEV_TO_MEM means the client wishes to push data from RAM into a FIFO.
- Scatter-gather DMA operations (for the pl300 at least) is restricted to cases where either the source or destination end point is a FIFO.  What if I wanted to do a scatter-gather operation from system RAM into FPGA (non-FIFO) memory?

Am I misunderstanding and/or overlooking something?  Does the DMA engine already provide a (undocumented) mechanism to specify address-increment behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this

```
pd->device_prep_dma_memcpy = pl330_prep_dma_memcpy;
pd->device_prep_dma_cyclic = pl330_prep_dma_cyclic;
pd->device_prep_slave_sg = pl330_prep_slave_sg;
```

It means you have different approaches like you have read in documentation. RAM-like transfers could be done, I suspect, via `device_prep_dma_memcpy()`.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered that from reading the pl330 driver.  It looks like I can specify the address increment behavior for this particular DMA controller driver (via the prep_dma_memcpy() or prep_slave_sg() methods).  BUT is this the convention used by all DMA controller drivers?   I do not want my DMA client driver to break if a new DMA controller driver is used.

Comment: You have to fix all drivers you would like to use anyway. The generic implementation allows you to use limited set of features. Different DMA controllers behaves differently, thus the user of DMA channel should cope with all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me (after looking to various drivers in a kernel) the only DMA transfer styles which allows you (indirectly) control auto-increment behavior is the ones which have `enum dma_transfer_direction` in its corresponding `device_prep_...` function.

And this parameter declared only for `device_prep_slave_sg` and `device_prep_dma_cyclic`, according to `include/linux/dmaengine.h`

Another option should be to use and `struct dma_interleaved_template` which allows you to specify increment behaviour directly. But support for this method is limited (only i.MX DMA driver does support it in 3.8 kernel, for example. And even this support seems to be limited)

So I think, we are stuck with `device_prep_slave_sg` case with all `sg`-related complexities for a some while.

That is that I am doing at the moment (although it is for accessing of some EBI-connected device on Atmel SAM9 SOC)

Another thing to consider is a device's bus width. `memcopy`-variant can perform different bus-width transfers, depending on a source and target addresses and sizes. And this may not match size of FIFO element.